# how to sort ArrayList by id and add to ArrayList ArrayList<ArrayList<DataPost>>

Tags: java, android, for-loop, kotlin

I have mList2 with values. There are values with the same id. How can I get a List or ArrayList in which objects with the same id are grouped and add it to  ArrayList>?

```
List<ProfileActivity.DataPost> mList2 = list;
    List<List<ProfileActivity.DataPost>> output = new ArrayList<List<ProfileActivity.DataPost>>();
    List<ProfileActivity.DataPost> itemsAlreadyGrouped = new ArrayList<ProfileActivity.DataPost>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mList2.size(); i++) {
        List<ProfileActivity.DataPost> groupList = new ArrayList<ProfileActivity.DataPost>();
        boolean groupCandidateFound = false;
        if (!itemsAlreadyGrouped.contains(mList2.get(i))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mList2.size(); j++) {
                if (mList2.get(i).getIds_post().equals(mList2.get(j).getIds_post())) {
                    groupList.add(mList2.get(i));
                    groupCandidateFound = true;
                }
            }
            if (groupCandidateFound) {
                itemsAlreadyGrouped.add(mList2.get(i));
            }
        }
        if (groupList.size() > 0) {
            output.add(groupList);
        }
    }

    //Let's test the logic
    for (List<ProfileActivity.DataPost> group : output) {
        System.out.println(group);
        Toast.makeText(context, group.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
```

**DataPost**

```
data class DataPost(var text:String? = null, var photo:String? = null,
                     var type:String = "",
                     var ids_post:String = "", var position:String? = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `ProfileActivity.DataPost` class `implements Comparable<ProfileActivity.DataPost>` interface, the implement the `compareTo(ProfileActivity.DataPost o)` method

```
@Override
public void compareTo(ProfileActivity.DataPost o){
    return getIds_post().compareTo(o.getIds_post());
}
```

Then just invoke `Collections.sort(list)`